# spring 3 @controller not able to inject service object which has @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, transactions

I am using Spring 3 MVC, I have a problem in injecting the Objects.
I created the Controller Object with the `@Controller`. And I have created a Service Object with the `@Service` Object. I injected the service object in the controller with AutoWire.
And I created the DAO Object, and injected in the Service Object, and Tested the application , it is running fine.
Then I put `@Transactional` on DAO, then also it worked fine. But when I put the `@Transactional` on service object,It is Giving me the problem. At the time of deploying , at the Controller it says as "

> Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.erudicus.controller.LoginController.setLoginService(com.erudicus.model.service.LoginServiceImpl); nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch".

Here is the Code
Controller

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
     private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LoginController.class);

    private LoginServiceImpl loginService = null;


    public LoginServiceImpl getLoginService() {
        return loginService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setLoginService(LoginServiceImpl loginService) {
                this.loginService = loginService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login" , method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute(new Login());
            return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/loginDetails", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView create(@Valid Login login, BindingResult result) {
      }
}
```

Service Object

```
@Service
public class LoginServiceImpl implements LoginService {

    private LoginDao loginDao = null;


    public LoginDao getLoginDao() {
        return loginDao;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setLoginDao(LoginDao loginDao) {
        this.loginDao = loginDao;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public Login getUserDetails(String userId) {
           return getLoginDao().getUserDetails(userId);
    }
}
```

Dao

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public class LoginDaoImpl extends SqlSessionDaoSupport implements LoginDao {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public Login getUserDetails(String userId) {
    }
}
```

In the Configuration I specified

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />
    <!-- enable autowire -->
    <!-- enable transaction demarcation with annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
 <context:annotation-config/>
```

Any one can please help

Comment: I asked a similar question if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713033/autowire-strange-problem

Answer (score 11):

Define the field to be an interface, rather than a concrete class. (So `UserService` instead of `UserServiceImpl`). You can add the `@Transactional` annotation on the concrete class - it will work.

The problem is that by default spring uses JDK proxies (`java.lang.reflect.Proxy`) which are interface-only proxies. Your concrete class is then used by the invocation handler, but you cannot cast to it.

If there is no interface, spring uses another method - CGLIB, which subclasses the target class in order to make the proxy.

You can use `<aop:scoped-proxy />` to configure the proxying stragegy (`proxy-target-class`) per bean.

Comment: Yes, It Worked, Thank you for that, But I have another question, Anotation are not inherited, And my service interface is not annoted with @transaction, I annoted in the concerete class as @Transaction, will the transactions is loaded by the service, when a controller some operations on Service which has a Transaction set. And also please explain what is problem with my earlier version of the code.

Comment: I was having a similar problem and your answer and explanation helped me out, Thanks!

Comment: Helped me out too. Thanks !!! I though I could quickly autowire dao's three levels deep w/o the use of interfaces. It worked for two levels. At the third it started working with proxies. Why ... mystery. :-)