# Spring Boot 3 Update: No qualifying bean of type 'jakarta.xml.ws.WebServiceContext' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, jakarta-migration

After the update from spring boot 2.7. to version 3 the strange error occurred, that no qualifying bean of type 'jakarta.xml.ws.WebServiceContext' is available.  I followed the migration steps (javax to jakarta) and compiling the project works fine, but it cannot be started.
The SOAP request needs the WebServiceContext because I need to extract some information from the header/body.
Is there any way to inject the WebServiceContext? It was working fine in Spring Version 2.7

I already eliminated third-party libs that included older Spring versions so that an older version does not interfere with the functionality of Spring.
I also looked at several discussions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71791427/webservicecontext-in-spring-boot-application) but none of them was helpful.
As recommended, I tried to inject the WebServiceContext with a setter with the same result.

```
@jakarta.jws.WebService
public class MyEndpoint {
...

    private WebServiceContext context;

    @Resource
    public void setContext(WebServiceContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

had similar issue after spring-boot upgrade and we fixed this issue by adding below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this problem when upgrading our application to Spring 6 and CXF 4.

It turns out that Spring 6 removed the JAX-WS support that was needed to make injecting WebServiceContext work. Unfortunately, this was not mentioned in anywhere in the release notes or documentation, as far as I can tell.

See these two tickets for more information:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27422
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-8666

You didn't mention which JAX-WS implementation you are using.

- If you're using CXF with Spring Boot, you should include `org.apache.cxf:cxf-spring-boot-autoconfigure` (or `org.apache.cxf:cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws`) in your project.
- If you're using CXF with Spring but not Spring Boot, I think the only practical solution is copying the code of [JaxWsAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/main/integration/spring-boot/autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/spring/boot/autoconfigure/jaxws/CxfJaxwsAutoConfiguration.java) in your project.

- If you're using a different JAX-WS implementation, you'll need to check if it has any support for Spring 6. If not, I think copying JaxWsAutoConfiguration code mentioned above should work (it's not specific to CXF).

Comment: Did you verify if that's working?

Comment: It worked for us.

Comment: ok. You mean to say adding org.apache.cxf:cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws worked?

Comment: I found something from CXF. I'm doing R&D. They have shown example with jakarta approach.

Comment: Ah, we use Spring without Spring Boot. I thought I mentioned that. So we just copied the relevant code in our project, rather than pulling in all the Spring Boot auto-configuration stuff.

Comment: I guess I found a way without copying stuff :) Just testing at this moment. Let see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Apache CXF Team has given complete example on how to integrate **Spring** with **CXF 4**.

Apache CXF 4 supports both Spring 6 and Spring Boot 3.

Links that helped me to reach to the solution:

- Official Apache CXF 4 with Vanilla Spring Approach Github Example [here](https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/main/distribution/src/main/release/samples/java_first_spring_support).
- Official Apache CXF 4 with Spring Boot Approach Github Example [here](https://github.com/apache/cxf/tree/main/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jaxws_spring_boot).
- Official Apache CXF 4 Documentation For Setting up Servlet Configuration Docs (Spring) [here](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html).

---

Now, I will be demonstrating the examples with fresh and sample projects created from scratch:

**Spring Boot 3 and Apache CXF 4** :

So, I will be using **Spring Boot 3.0.10**, **Apache CXF 4.0.3** & **JDK 17.0.8**

My Project Structure:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── example
│   │   │           └── test
│   │   │               ├── SampleEndPoint.java
│   │   │               ├── SampleEndPointApplication.java
│   │   │               ├── SampleEndPointInterface.java
│   │   │               └── WebServiceConfiguration.java
│   │   └── resources
│   │       └── application.properties
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-3-cxf-4-example</artifactId>
    <name>Spring Boot 3 and CXF 4 Web Services Sample</name>
    <description>Spring Boot 3 and CXF 4 Web Services Sample</description>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
            <exclusions><!-- CXF uses java.util.logging by default -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-features-metrics</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.example.test.SampleEndPointApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <requireJavaVersion>
                            <version>${java.version}</version>
                        </requireJavaVersion>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Note:** These are important dependencies - `cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws`, `spring-boot-starter-web-services` & `cxf-rt-features-metrics` (which comes with `jakarta.xml.ws-api-3.0.1`)

Maven downloaded dependencies for the project (Screenshot from IntelliJ):

[image]

SampleEndPointInterface:

```
import jakarta.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface SampleEndPointInterface {

    void printTextOnConsole(String text);

}
```

SampleEndPoint:

```
import jakarta.annotation.Resource;
import jakarta.jws.WebService;
import jakarta.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.example.test.SampleEndPointInterface")
public class SampleEndPoint implements SampleEndPointInterface {

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext context;

    @Override
    public void printTextOnConsole(String text) {
        System.out.println("Text Sent: " + text);
    }
}
```

Note: As per CXF 4 docs, you have to use `@jakarta.annotation.Resource` to inject `WebServiceContext` Bean into the Service and not `@Autowired`.

WebServiceConfiguration:

```
import jakarta.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Bus bus;

    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, new SampleEndPoint());
        endpoint.publish("/sample");
        return endpoint;
    }
}
```

SampleEndPointApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleEndPointApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleEndPointApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
cxf.path=/services
```

The application starts successfully.

Application logs:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:62168,suspend=y,server=n -javaagent:/Users/anish/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2022.3/captureAgent/debugger-agent.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/anish/cxf/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jaxws_spring_boot/target/classes:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws/4.0.3/cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws-4.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/3.0.10/spring-boot-starter-3.0.10.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/3.0.10/spring-boot-3.0.10.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/6.0.11/spring-context-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/3.0.10/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.10.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/6.0.11/spring-core-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/6.0.11/spring-jcl-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.33/snakeyaml-1.33.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/3.0.10/spring-boot-starter-web-3.0.10.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/3.0.10/spring-boot-starter-json-3.0.10.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.14.3/jackson-databind-2.14.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.14.3/jackson-annotations-2.14.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.14.3/jackson-core-2.14.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.14.3/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.14.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.14.3/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.14.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.14.3/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.14.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/3.0.10/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.0.10.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/10.1.12/tomcat-embed-core-10.1.12.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/10.1.12/tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.12.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/6.0.11/spring-web-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-observation/1.10.9/micrometer-observation-1.10.9.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/io/micrometer/micrometer-commons/1.10.9/micrometer-commons-1.10.9.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/6.0.11/spring-webmvc-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/6.0.11/spring-expression-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-spring-boot-autoconfigure/4.0.3/cxf-spring-boot-autoconfigure-4.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-transports-http/4.0.3/cxf-rt-transports-http-4.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws/4.0.3/cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-4.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/xml-resolver/xml-resolver/1.2/xml-resolver-1.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/9.5/asm-9.5.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-soap/4.0.3/cxf-rt-bindings-soap-4.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-wsdl/4.0.3/cxf-rt-wsdl-4.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/wsdl4j/wsdl4j/1.6.3/wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb/4.0.3/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-4.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-bindings-xml/4.0.3/cxf-rt-bindings-xml-4.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-frontend-simple/4.0.3/cxf-rt-frontend-simple-4.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/angus/angus-mail/1.0.0/angus-mail-1.0.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/jakarta/mail/jakarta.mail-api/2.1.0/jakarta.mail-api-2.1.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-ws-addr/4.0.3/cxf-rt-ws-addr-4.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-ws-policy/4.0.3/cxf-rt-ws-policy-4.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/neethi/neethi/3.2.0/neethi-3.2.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/angus/angus-activation/2.0.1/angus-activation-2.0.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/jakarta/validation/jakarta.validation-api/3.0.2/jakarta.validation-api-3.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/3.0.10/spring-boot-starter-validation-3.0.10.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/10.1.12/tomcat-embed-el-10.1.12.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/8.0.1.Final/hibernate-validator-8.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.4.3.Final/jboss-logging-3.4.3.Final.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.5.1/classmate-1.5.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-rt-features-metrics/4.0.3/cxf-rt-features-metrics-4.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/ws/jakarta.xml.ws-api/3.0.1/jakarta.xml.ws-api-3.0.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api/3.0.1/jakarta.xml.bind-api-3.0.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/jakarta/xml/soap/jakarta.xml.soap-api/2.0.1/jakarta.xml.soap-api-2.0.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/jakarta/jws/jakarta.jws-api/3.0.0/jakarta.jws-api-3.0.0.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/cxf/cxf-core/4.0.3/cxf-core-4.0.3.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/jakarta/annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/2.1.1/jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/3.0.2/jaxb-runtime-3.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-core/3.0.2/jaxb-core-3.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/txw2/3.0.2/txw2-3.0.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/sun/istack/istack-commons-runtime/4.0.1/istack-commons-runtime-4.0.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/woodstox/woodstox-core/6.5.1/woodstox-core-6.5.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/woodstox/stax2-api/4.2.1/stax2-api-4.2.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/apache/ws/xmlschema/xmlschema-core/2.3.1/xmlschema-core-2.3.1.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/jakarta/activation/jakarta.activation-api/2.1.2/jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/6.0.11/spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:/Users/anish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/6.0.10/spring-aop-6.0.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar com.example.test.SampleEndPointApplication
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:62168', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v3.0.10)

[2023-10-05 23:08:47.231] - 43062 INFO [main] --- com.example.test.SampleEndPointApplication: Starting SampleEndPointApplication using Java 17.0.8 with PID 43062 (/Users/anish/cxf/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jaxws_spring_boot/target/classes started by anish in /Users/anish/cxf/distribution/src/main/release/samples/jaxws_spring_boot)
[2023-10-05 23:08:47.278] - 43062 INFO [main] --- com.example.test.SampleEndPointApplication: No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
Oct 05, 2023 11:08:48 PM org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer initialize
INFO: Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
Oct 05, 2023 11:08:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Oct 05, 2023 11:08:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.12]
Oct 05, 2023 11:08:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Oct 05, 2023 11:08:48 PM org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext prepareWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1393 ms
Oct 05, 2023 11:08:49 PM org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean buildServiceFromClass
INFO: Creating Service {http://test.example.com/}SampleEndPointService from class com.example.test.SampleEndPointInterface
Oct 05, 2023 11:08:49 PM org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl initDestination
INFO: Setting the server's publish address to be /sample
Oct 05, 2023 11:08:49 PM org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer start
INFO: Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
Oct 05, 2023 11:08:49 PM org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger logStarted
INFO: Started SampleEndPointApplication in 3.079 seconds (process running for 3.456)
```

This means that Spring via Jakarta was able to inject that WebServiceContext bean with no issues.

Screenshot of the output:

Postman:

[image]

Console Output:

[image]

WebServiceContext Object in Debug Mode:

[image]

**Vanilla Spring 6 and Apache CXF 4:**

So, I will be using **Spring 6.0.12**, **Apache CXF 4.0.3**, **Jetty Server 11.0.16** for deploying my WAR file & **JDK 17.0.8**

Project Structure:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       │   └── com
│       │       └── example
│       │           └── test
│       │               ├── SampleEndPoint.java
│       │               ├── SampleEndPointInterface.java
│       │               └── Server.java
│       ├── resources
│       │   └── log4j.xml
│       └── webapp
│           └── WEB-INF
│               ├── beans.xml
│               └── web.xml
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>demo.example.text</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-spring-6-test</artifactId>
    <name>Spring 6 CXF Sample</name>
    <description>Spring 6 CXF Sample</description>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-features-logging</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <rules>
                        <requireJavaVersion>
                            <version>${java.version}</version>
                        </requireJavaVersion>
                    </rules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>cxf-spring-6-test</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Maven downloaded dependencies for the project (Screenshot from IntelliJ):

[image]

**Note:** I have removed jetty related dependencies as you don't need them. You can generate the war file and deploy it on a standalone tomcat server and test it.

Also, I needed all the mentioned dependencies to make the things work.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
        PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>Spring 6 CXF Example</display-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config-location</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>hide-service-list-page</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
         http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
         http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>

    <jaxws:endpoint id="sampleEndPoint" implementor="com.example.test.SampleEndPoint" address="/sample">
        <jaxws:features>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingFeature"/>
        </jaxws:features>
    </jaxws:endpoint>

</beans>
```

SampleEndPointInterface:

```
import jakarta.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface SampleEndPointInterface {

    void printTextOnConsole(String text);

}
```

SampleEndPoint:

```
import jakarta.annotation.Resource;
import jakarta.jws.WebService;
import jakarta.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
 
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.example.test.SampleEndPointInterface")
public class SampleEndPoint implements SampleEndPointInterface {

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext context;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleEndPoint.class);

    @Override
    public void printTextOnConsole(String text) {
        LOGGER.info("Text Sent: " + text);
    }
}
```

Server starts successfully.

Application logs:

[image]

Again, This means that Spring via Jakarta was able to inject that WebServiceContext bean with no issues.

Screenshot of the output:

Postman:

[image]

Console Output:

[image]

WebServiceContext Object in Debug Mode:

[image]

That's all.

Comment: Hi Anish. I mostly regarded this issue as solved (see my own earlier answer) and was busy with other tasks. I tried your vanilla Spring example. But the way it is setup, Spring doesn't try to configure the SampleEndPoint class (@AutoWired in that class is ignored). I don't know why that would be, but I don't really have time to further look into this.

Comment: @pdw Ok. But they have given this approach only right? WebServiceContext is part of Jakarta. They recommend using Jakarta approach in Spring.

Comment: @pdw But at least it works right? You have to use `@Resource` way only.

Answer (score -1):

if your are using maven try adding these dependency in pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

if it doesn't work you can also try changing @Resource to @Autowired
This may help Spring recognize the WebServiceContext as a bean that needs to be injected.

```
@jakarta.jws.WebService
public class MyEndpoint {
...
    @Autowired
    private WebServiceContext context;

    
    public void setContext(WebServiceContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
...

@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public WebServiceContext webServiceContext() {
        return new WebServiceContext() {
            // implementation of WebServiceContext methods
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The dependency is already in the pom. Also the approach with Autowired I have tried without success. With `@Autowired(required = false)` the application is able to start but the variable context is null.
SpringBoot 3 must have some strange effects of the injections of the bean

Comment: after adding dependency, try rebuilding and running your application again

Answer (score -1):

I have faced this issue for a couple other beans in Spring Boot 3. Each time the issue has been related to trying to autowire a Bean that is an interface, not a class. One solution is to register a bean that returns an instance of a class that implements the interface in question.

In this case, the `WebServiceContext` from Jakarta is the interface, and the implementation class I chose is from `org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context`. I registered the following bean in an @Configuration class, and it fixed the issue:

```java
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.context.WebServiceContextImpl;
import jakarta.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

  @Bean
  public WebServiceContext webServiceContext() {
    return new WebServiceContextImpl();
  }
```

This approach makes configurations explicit, which may be nice. As a side note, there may also be a spring-boot-starter dependency you can include, which provides basic implementations for interfaces based on application.properties values, so that you don't have to configure them. I was not able to find one for this case, but I didn't look for very long