# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

i am new to Spring and hibernate and i am stuck at this problem. i have been searching around for a fix but although there are a lot of questions on this, they do not seem to solve my problem. i am using spring 3.1.0 with hibernate 3.6.9 and making a web application with using spring mvc. After a lot of looking around, i managed to solve it with the following config

**web.xml**

> `<listener>
>           <description>Spring context loader</description>
>           <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
>       </listener>`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

> `<bean
>           class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
>           <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
>           <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
>       </bean>`

```
<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven  />
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- Scans within the base package of the application for @Components to 
    configure as beans -->
<!-- @Controller, @Service, @Configuration, etc. -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.emumba.cricketcalendar" />



<import resource="hibernate-context.xml"/>
```

**hibernate-context.xml**

> `<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
>           destroy-method="close">
>           <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
>           <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
>           <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
>           <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
>       </bean>`

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.emumba.cricketcalendar.domain.Match</value>
            <value>com.emumba.cricketcalendar.domain.Ground</value>
            <value>com.emumba.cricketcalendar.domain.Umpire</value>
            <value>com.emumba.cricketcalendar.domain.Country</value>
            <value>com.emumba.cricketcalendar.domain.CricketStatus</value>
            <value>com.emumba.cricketcalendar.domain.Series</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

And then i put the @Transactional on my service and this exception was gone. But then my autowiring stops working, the autowired annotation doesn't work and beans with autowired properties start throwing exception. i remove the @transactional annotation from my service and it again starts working but the "no hibernate session bound to thread " exception returns

So i am really confused , any help would be greatly appreciated

**EDIT** Service Code

> @Service(value="calendarManager")
>   public class CalendarMangerImpl implements CalendarManager {

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("matchDao")
public MatchDaoHibernate matchDao;

@Override
public List<Match> getAllMatches() {
    List<Match> matches=new ArrayList<Match>();
    matches=matchDao.findAll();
    return matches;
}
```

}

Comment: Can we see the code for your service?

Comment: I was about to come on to the JDK vs CGLIB proxy issue. Looks like you've got your answer.

Comment: @Alex ya i did, finally :) thanx anyways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the service class with reference to its interface and not the actual class as spring uses interface based proxies by default

```
Spring AOP defaults to using standard J2SE dynamic proxies for AOP proxies. This enables 
any interface (or set of interfaces) to be proxied.
```

Comment: @Arvind A all my daos are extending a generic dao and when i moved the @transactional from the child to the parent calss , it gave this `org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Cannot proxy target class because CGLIB2 is not available. Add CGLIB to the class path or specify proxy interfaces.`

Comment: @khizar one more query - How are you using the service ? I hope you're using CalendarManager myservice and not  CalendarMangerImpl  myservice from wherever you're calling it .

Comment: well i am using the CalendarManagerImpl , because the @ Service annotation is on the class not the interface. is it wrong ?

Comment: Yes . use CalendarManager myservice . The service annotation  will be detected even in this case . You're using interface base proxying - Hence you need to have an interface there .

Comment: @Khizar add CGLIB jar to your class path as you are doing class based proxies instead of JDK interface-based proxies

Comment: @khizar - See the discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713033/autowire-strange-problem . The problem is same as yours .

Comment: @AravindA thanx alot mate, that was the problem, even after using the interface reference for the service, i was still using class reference for the dao, as soon as i changed it , it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest first [go through this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/11/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example.html) simple example clear all the concepts. It will help you in future as well.

Comment: thanx but i have already done some simple examples and basically i was just taking it to more complex problems...

Comment: @Khizar Can please verify your config settings?